# Generating Report using Crystal Report(version 13) view in Model Popup Print Button not working?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, printing, crystal-reports

I was developed one small application using Asp.NET with C# (Web Application). My Environment is Crystal Report(version 13) with visual Studio 2010 .while Generating Reports Records are Displayed. but print button was not working? What are the possiblities are there for this problem. Please any one could Explain this...

Comment: whats your default printer in crystal report? have you check it with all browsers.

Comment: Not working on all browser ... before that i was changed my report version 10.0 to 13.0 so this the problem ah?

Comment: i thinks so by changing report version 10 to 13 it could be the possible problem, have you change report viewer version also ?

Comment: k thank you... my adobe reader having problem so its not working... I found the Error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My adobe reader having problem so its not working... I found the Error... After Reinstalling it was working...